# Make a variable permanent, javascript, php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

On this Url https://mappingforyou.eu/gallery/osmmap.php?/category/35&v=2

a "category" variable was set to 35. I'd like the page to set that category to 35 permanently. How should I do ?

I'm using https://github.com/Piwigo/piwigo-openstreetmap  .

The files are map2.tpl and functions_map. php

Please help.

*PS : last time my post was closed without explanation and I was prevented from posting again. This doesn't occur on gis stackechange, but this occurs here and I can't figure out why. I'm here for the purpose of learning and I'm a beginner so please at least give an explanation*

```
    function osm_get_gps($page)
{
    // Limit search by category, by tag, by smartalbum
    $LIMIT_SEARCH="";
    $INNER_JOIN="";
    if (isset($page['section']))
    {
        if ($page['section'] === 'categories' and isset($page['category']) and isset($page['category']['id']) )
        {
            $LIMIT_SEARCH = "FIND_IN_SET(".$page['category']['id'].", c.uppercats) AND ";
            $INNER_JOIN = "INNER JOIN ".CATEGORIES_TABLE." AS c ON ic.category_id = c.id";
        }
        if ($page['section'] === 'tags' and isset($page['tags']) and isset($page['tags'][0]['id']) )
        {
            $items = get_image_ids_for_tags( array_reduce( $page['tags'], 'osm_get_page_tag_id' ) );
            if ( !empty($items) )
            {
                $LIMIT_SEARCH = "ic.image_id IN (".implode(',', $items).") AND ";
            }
        }
        if ($page['section'] === 'tags' and isset($page['category']) and isset($page['category']['id']) )
        {
            $LIMIT_SEARCH = "FIND_IN_SET(".$page['category']['id'].", c.uppercats) AND ";
            $INNER_JOIN = "INNER JOIN ".CATEGORIES_TABLE." AS c ON ic.category_id = c.id";
        }
    }

    $forbidden = get_sql_condition_FandF(
        array
        (
            'forbidden_categories' => 'ic.category_id',
            'visible_categories' => 'ic.category_id',
            'visible_images' => 'i.id'
        ),
        "\n AND"
    );

    /* Get all GPX tracks */
    $query="SELECT i.path FROM ".IMAGES_TABLE." AS i
            INNER JOIN (".IMAGE_CATEGORY_TABLE." AS ic ".$INNER_JOIN.") ON i.id = ic.image_id
            WHERE ".$LIMIT_SEARCH." `path` LIKE '%.gpx' ".$forbidden." ";

    return array_from_query($query, 'path');
}

function osm_get_items($page)
{
    // Limit search by category, by tag, by smartalbum
    $LIMIT_SEARCH="";
    $INNER_JOIN="";
    if (isset($page['section']))
    {
        if ($page['section'] === 'categories' and isset($page['category']) and isset($page['category']['id']) )
        {
            $LIMIT_SEARCH = "FIND_IN_SET(".$page['category']['id'].", c.uppercats) AND ";
            $INNER_JOIN = "INNER JOIN ".CATEGORIES_TABLE." AS c ON ic.category_id = c.id";
        }
        if ($page['section'] === 'tags' and isset($page['tags']) and isset($page['tags'][0]['id']) )
        {
            $items = get_image_ids_for_tags( array_reduce( $page['tags'], 'osm_get_page_tag_id' ) );
            if ( !empty($items) )
            {
                $LIMIT_SEARCH = "ic.image_id IN (".implode(',', $items).") AND ";
            }
        }
        if ($page['section'] === 'tags' and isset($page['category']) and isset($page['category']['id']) )
        {
            $LIMIT_SEARCH = "FIND_IN_SET(".$page['category']['id'].", c.uppercats) AND ";
            $INNER_JOIN = "INNER JOIN ".CATEGORIES_TABLE." AS c ON ic.category_id = c.id";
        }
    }
```

Comment: `I'd like the page to set that category to 35 permanently.` you want all visitors to get category 35?

Comment: @James correct.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, isn't this URL `https://mappingforyou.eu/gallery/osmmap.php?/category/35` already giving results only for cat=35? I mean, it is already permanent, isn't it?

Comment: unless, maybe you want this URL `https://mappingforyou.eu/gallery/osmmap.php` to always be set for showing cat=35 only?

Comment: There are a few ways to do this, but all of them use the technique of "storing that value somewhere on the server".  In a database field, in a text file, in an ini file.

Comment: @GrafiCode yes, I need https://mappingforyou.eu/gallery/osmmap.php to give results only for category 35

Comment: ok then. I think you just need to replace `".$page['category']['id']."` inside your queries with `35`. But please don't take this for granted, I'm no expert, maybe someone else could post an actual answer

Comment: It's very unclear how you get the category from the URL. How is `$page` created/populated? How are you actually handling the request? The question seem to be missing the most crucial parts of the code. Either way, where you parse that category id out from the query string, just hard code it as `35` if no other id was found.

Comment: @M.Eriksson the code is at https://github.com/Piwigo/piwigo-openstreetmap/blob/master/include/functions_map.php#L70 as I was hoping to include the relevant parts of it

Comment: Please don't link to code off-site. All relevant code/errors _must_ be included into the question itself, so please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73754825/edit) the question and include the relevant parts. And since the code you've posted only uses the category id it gets, it's not relevant here. You should only need to update the code where you parse the URL to get the id. Btw, why aren't you setting the category like this:  `?category=123&v=2`? The current format requires you to parse it out manually, which seems unnecessary.

Comment: Btw, what does this question have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: @M.Eriksson I might need help because I can't find the relevabt part; I thought it was that. I'd like to hard code the category if It works like this

Comment: @M.Eriksson i'm trying to remove ?category=123 to get a friendlier Url.  the code is mainly javascript elsewhere, I still have trouble to make the difference

Comment: If you're looking to make more user/seo friendly URL's, I would recommend that you read about the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) and then use a [router](https://packagist.org/?query=router) to handle the URL's in your application. That's what the majority of modern frameworks/CMS's etc are using.

Comment: @GrafiCode thanks but what i get is 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected integer "35" in /var/www/html/gallery/plugins/piwigo-openstreetmap/include/functions_map0.php on line 64

Comment: @GrafiCode I got Parse error: syntax error, unexpected integer "35" in /var/www/html/gallery/plugins/piwigo-openstreetmap/include/functions_map0.php on line 64